# Sencha Touch 2 - Iphone app - blank white screen

Tags: iphone, extjs, screen

I am building iphone app using sencha touch 2 command. App works fine except, when I open it on iphone it shows splash screen and then shows white blank screen for 1-2 seconds. I believe it could be the issue of gathering all sencha js files to execute. But is there any way, we can show temporary screen instead of white blank screen?

I am not using phone gap to build iphone app.

Thanks,
Viral.

Answer (score 0):

In phonegap based applications, there will be a provision for increasing the splash screen duration. Search for the same thing. You may find a solution for the way you are building your app(not phonegap)

Edit:  Try lazyload.. i.e., while the content is loading use a throbber like thing. Because blank screen may seems to be like the application is not working properly

Comment: thanks for reply. Do you mean that I might have to check with sencha library if it can provide me facility to hold splash screen for more time?

Comment: yes, try to add sleep or delay function, when u call the splash screen

Comment: I don't think sleep or delay will work because splash screen comes first before Launch function called of sencha. Right now, I have removed splash images from loading folder, so it directly shows white screen and then launching app. Still I will be looking for good solution to this.